# XML Data is not Facet-valid With Respect To Pattern '[A-FH-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-QS-Z]'

Tags: xml, xsd

I am getting the below Error when using "34" as my value:

> Cvc-pattern-valid: Value '34' Is Not Facet-valid With Respect To
>   Pattern '[A-FH-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-QS-Z]' For Type 'TKodKrajuJPK'., Line
>   '86', Column '56'.

Below is the pattern of the Type from the XSD:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="TKodKraju">
        <xsd:union memberTypes="etd:TKodKraju tns:TKodKrajuISO"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="TKodKrajuISO">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Uzupełnienie słownika kodów krajów o brakujące kody wg ISO 3166 oraz unijny kod dla Grecji - EL</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
            <xsd:enumeration value="SX">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>WYSPA SINT MAARTEN (CZĘŚĆ HOLENDERSKA WYSPY)</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="BQ">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>BONAIRE, SINT EUSTATIUS I SABA</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="SS">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>SUDAN POŁUDNIOWY</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CW">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>CURAÇAO</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="EL">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>GRECJA</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="TKodKrajuJPK">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Wyklucznie ze słownika kodów krajów kodu dla Grecji - GR</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="tns:TKodKraju">
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-FH-Z][A-Z]"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z][A-QS-Z]"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

From what I understood, it should be a Capital Letter within the range of `A-Z`. However, when I use 'AA' it still errors out:

> Cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: 'AA' Is Not A Valid Value Of Union Type
>   'TKodKrajuJPK'., Line '86', Column '56'.

But when I use `BB` the error is resolved.

Can someone clarify what the valid values are and which pattern should I put in?

Answer (score 0):

These are regular expressions.
They define ranges of valid capital letters.

It seems that your XML contains a numerical value of 34. Which is obviously invalid. Additionally, you need to check what is behind the `<xsd:restriction base="tns:TKodKraju">` clause. Without that clause `AA` is passing the validation.

The latest exposure in the original post, pieces of XSD, means that the value needs to pass first validation against the enumerator "SX", "BQ", "SS", etc. and just after that the regular expression patterns.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="kod.xsd">
    <kod>AA</kod>
</root>
```

> XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="kod"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="kod">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[A-FH-Z][A-Z]"/>
                <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-QS-Z]"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

> Output

```
Running custom validation engine Saxonica 9.8.0.12 Validator...
SAXON-EE 9.8.0.12J from Saxonica validate complete
```

Comment: i modified it and tried `AA` but it still has an error. Also, what's the correct format? can you clarify further especially with the pattern `[A-FH-Z][A-Z]`?

Comment: I added a small example to the answer.

Comment: thank you for this, i've added more information regarding the `XSD`. greatly appreciate it if you clarify it a bit further. thank you!

Comment: I update the answer with the additional explanations.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two validation errors you are telling us about.

Firstly, "34" does not conform to the regular expression, because it only allows capital letters.

Secondly, "AA" is invalid for more complex reasons. The type `TKodKrajuJPK` is defined as a restriction of `TKodKraju`, and `TKodKraju` is defined as a union of `etd:TKodKraju` and `tns:TKodKrajuISO`. So to be valid, "AA" must satisfy the constraints (a) for the type `TKodKrajuJPK` (which it does) and (b) for one of the types `etd:TKodKraju` and `tns:TKodKrajuISO`.

You haven't shown us the type `etd:TKodKraju`, so we don't know whether it's valid against that (but the evidence suggests not), and it's certainly not valid against type `tns:TKodKrajuISO`. because that's an enumeration of 5 specific values.

So I think we need to see whether AA is valid against type `etd:TKodKraju`, and I suspect it isn't.

Comment: where do i get `etd:TKodKraju`? in my snippet above, that's the only place i see it.

Comment: It's presumably somewhere in the part of the schema you haven't shown us - probably an imported module, since it's a different namespace. Check your `xsd:import` declarations.